# Проблемы после генерации кода ISourceGenerator

Tags: c#, .net

покажу проблему на примере небольшого проекта

мой source generator

```
[Generator]
public class TestGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
    }

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(@"
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class Test
    {
        public void Testing()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(""Test"");
        }
    }
}
");

        context.AddSource("test.cs", SourceText.From(sb.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8));
    }
}
```

в проекте, в котором подключен анализатор, вот такие строки

```
<EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
<CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>..\ConsoleApp3\GeneratedFiles</CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>
```

потому что мне нужно обращаться прям к созданному файлу

но проблема заключается в том, что у меня есть этот файл физически и в оперативной памяти

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

из-за это происходят ошибки

```
Error   CS0111  Type 'Test' already defines a member called 'Testing' with the same parameter types
```

какие пути решения данной проблемы есть?

Comment: Модификатор `partial`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov пробовал, не помогает. Т.к, при обращении к этому классу namespace у того, что в анализаторе, и того, что под проектом, одинаковые. если изменить namespace после генерации, то при билде они все равно будут идентичные

Comment: Несколько вариантов на выбор: измените пространство имён, измените имя класса, измените имя метода, измените сигнатуру метода.